# Compile time fail for Typechecking

Tags: c++, c++17

My understanding of template is that when I write `void foo<T>(T x) {...}` and call `foo<int>(x);` and `foo<float>(x)` would generate `foo(int x)` and `foo(float x)`.

What I want is to type checking before some comparision, but since the compiler generates two version of the function, the comparision part will failed in compiling time.

My code is

```c
template <typename T>
      void print(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& matrix) {
          std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed;
          for (int j=0; j < matrix[0].size(); j++) {
              for (int i=0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
                  // Fail on this line ↓
                  if ((std::is_floating_point<T>::value) &&
                          (matrix[i][j] == std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest())) {
                      std::cout << "✗ ";
                      continue;
                  }
                  std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
              }
          }
          std::cout << "\n";
      }
```

On the othe file I called

```
util::print<float>(best_value);
util::print<Point>(best_policy);
```

Declaration

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> best_value;
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> best_policy;
```

How should I fix that problem while keeping the `print` function and do not have to add the comparision between `Point` and `float`?

Comment: Have you tried `std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`?

Comment: Please create a separate answer so that I can accept and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()` to `std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`

Comment: Can you explain what does `std::numeric_limits<Point>::lowest()` do? Currently  `std::numeric_limits<Point>::lowest()` seems to return `(0, 0)`. `Point` is a struct with two members `int x` and `int y`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits does not show any hint

Comment: From [std::numeric_limits::lowest](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest), for `/* non-specialized */ ` you got `T();` so in your case default constructed `Point`.

Comment: @MinhTriet: The standard permits you to define `std::numeric_limits<Point>` yourself. although it's not clear to me that there is a sensible definition to choose.

Answer (score 2):

In c++17, you might use `if constexpr` for condition known at compile time:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void print(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& matrix) {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed;
    for (const auto& row : matrix) {
        for (const auto& e : row) {
            if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>::value)) {
                if (e == std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest())) { // T instead of float?
                    std::cout << "✗ ";
                    continue;
                }
            }
            std::cout << e << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. I am trying to grab the concept of `numeric_limits<Point>` as seen in my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019189/compile-time-fail-for-typechecking/57019419#comment100570028_57019221

Comment: @MinhTriet, with this answer `numeric_limits<Point>` is never instantiated as it only appears within `if constexpr (false)`